# Style specific words in string after hashtag - php

Tags: php, arrays, find, styles

My scenario: I try to style some names after a hashtag in a string.

example:

```
$string = 'Lorem #Stewie Smith ipsum dolor #Peter Griffin sit amet, consectetuer #Stewie Griffin.';
```

First I want to put these names in a array like:

```
array(

    [item 1]
    [firstname] => 'Peter'
    [surname] => 'Griffin'

    [item 2]
    [firstname] => 'Stewie'
    [surname] => 'Griffin'

    [item 3]
    [firstname] => 'Stewie'
    [surname] => 'Smith'

)
```

so I can loop trough the array and check if the first name and surname exist in my database.

Database data:

| id | firstname | Surname |

| 1  | Peter     | Griffin |

| 2  | Stewie     | Smith |

After this validation I like to put a div around the first name and surname in the string.

Who knows the answer?

Thanks in advance

Comment: *Who knows the answer?* I do! What do I win?

Comment: A thank you very much :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a regular expression:

```
//Regular expression (explained below)
$re = "/\\#([a-zA-Z]*)\\s([a-zA-Z]*)/"; 

//String to search
$str = "Lorem #Stewie Smith ipsum dolor #Peter Griffin sit amet, consectetuer #Stewie Griffin."; 

//Get all matches into $matches variable
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

`$matches` is now:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => #Stewie Smith
            [1] => #Peter Griffin
            [2] => #Stewie Griffin
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Stewie
            [1] => Peter
            [2] => Stewie
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Smith
            [1] => Griffin
            [2] => Griffin
        )

)
```

So each name is contained and accessible with:

```
$matches[0][n] //full match
$matches[1][n] //first name
$matches[2][n] //last name
```

Put it into an array:

```
$names = [];

foreach($matches[0] as $i => $v){
    $names[] = array("firstname" => $matches[1][$i], "lastname" => $matches[2][$i]);
}
```

Now `$names` is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [firstname] => Stewie
            [lastname] => Smith
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [firstname] => Peter
            [lastname] => Griffin
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [firstname] => Stewie
            [lastname] => Griffin
        )

)
```

---

From here, you can loop through this array, checking with your database, validating as you see fit and then doing whatever you want with the resulting data.

Comment: You sir won 'the thank you very much'! Thx! All day coding sometimes makes your head a little woozy ;)